simple differential inequality
I'm a differential geometry person so I'm not used to analysis, and I ran into this weird inequality when I was observing an example. Are there any smooth function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is surjective and $\frac{df}{dx}(x)\geq(f(x))^6$? If it was just $\frac{df}{dx}(x)\geq f(x)$ it would be easy since for example $f(x)=\operatorname{sinh}x, x\in\mathbb{R}$ would satisfy the inequality. However for $\frac{df}{dx}(x)\geq(f(x))^6$ I could not find.

Do you want an example for every interval $I$ or just for some interval $I$?

Your $f(x)=xe^x$ is not surjective on any $I\subseteq\mathbb{R}$.

@AngaeMT Of course. I don't mean one example for every interval, but for every interval an example. I just wondered which $I$ is allowed.

Thank you for corrections! I edited the original question.

I think there is no such function:
Assume that there is such a function $f$. Surjectivity yields that there is some $x_0$ such that $f(x_0) =1$. Since $f$ is increasing, then $f(x)\ge 1$ $(x \ge x_0)$. Now, for $x \ge x_0$:
$$
\frac{1}{5}\left(\frac{1}{(f(x_0))^5} - \frac{1}{(f(x))^5}\right)=\int_{x_0}^x\frac{f'(t)}{(f(t))^6} dt\ge x-x_0.
$$
Hence
$$
0<\frac{1}{(f(x))^5} \le \frac{1}{(f(x_0))^5} - 5 (x-x_0) = 1-5(x-x_0).
$$
But this is wrong for $x\ge 1/5+x_0$, a contradiction.
